# Rails: How to conditionally apply ActiveRecord sorting by one attribute based on through association or other property

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sorting, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am building out a tag-based forum in Rails 4, where topics can be associated with tags.

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :taggings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings
  ...
  scope :sort_by_latest_message, -> { order(latest_message_at: :desc) }
  scope :sort_by_sticky, -> { order(sticky: :desc) }
  ...
  scope :without_tags, -> { where.not(id: Tagging.select(:topic_id).uniq) }
  scope :with_tags, -> { joins(:tags).where("tag_id IS NOT NULL").uniq }
  ...
end
```

Topics also have a boolean column called "sticky."

**The issue**: I want to be able to have topics to sort in a manner that places topics with the sticky property at the top of the list, but only if that topic has an association with at least one of a specified list of tags. Topics will then be sorted by the latest_message_at property.

This all occurs AFTER a filtering process.

So for example, the list of topics will contain topics with tags X, Y, and Z, but only sticky topics with tag X should truly be considered sticky, so any topics that have the sticky property but are associated with tags Y or Z instead of tag X should be sorted normally (by latest message). So ultimately, the list will have sticky topics under tag X at the top (sorted by latest message), then all other topics under tag X plus topics under tag Y and Z whether they are sticky or not, sorted by the latest_message_at property.

I currently have a setup like this:

```
def self.combine_sort_with_sticky(tag_ids, primary_sort)
  if tag_ids.empty?
    relevent_sticky_topics = without_tags.where(sticky: true)
    other_topics = union_scope(*[with_tags, without_tags.where(sticky: false)]) # union_scope is a method that creates an SQL union based on the scopes within
  else
    relevent_sticky_topics = joins(:tags).where("tag_id IN (?)", tag_ids).uniq.where(sticky: true)
    other_topics = joins(:tags).where("tag_id NOT IN (?) OR sticky = ?", tag_ids, false).uniq
  end
  combined_topics = relevent_sticky_topics.send(primary_sort) + other_topics.send(primary_sort) # Order is important, otherwise stickies will be at the bottom.
  combined_topics.uniq
end
```

So when I call combine_sort_with_sticky([1], :sort_by_latest_message), only sticky topics with the tag of ID 1 AND the sticky property are moved to the front of the list. I'll also note that when not filtering on any tag, only topics without tags should be considered sticky.

This appears to give the results I want, but that + operator between the two sorted queries has me concerned, as it converts the ActiveRecord association to an Array object.

What I am looking for is a way to maintain the ActiveRecord association (such as a scope, or potentially another class model) while conditionally applying the first of the two sorting scopes. Topic.all.sort_by_sticky.sort_by_latest_message is close to what I want, but the problem is that it indiscriminately sorts by the sticky property, rather than only considering sticky topics with certain tags as true stickies.

I have been playing around with scopes like the following:

```
scope :sort_by_relevant_sticky, ->(tag_ids) { joins(:tags).order("CASE WHEN tag_id IN (?) THEN sticky ELSE latest_message_at END DESC", tag_ids).uniq }
```

but that doesn't seem to be working. I am not incredibly familiar with conditional SQL.

My database in Production is Postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an actual solution for your problem, but I'd take a look at this: https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on :)